# Download files by chunks in multiple threads in Go

Tags: multithreading, http, go, chunks

I need to download files, chunk by chunk in multiple threads.
For example, I have 1k files, each file ~100Mb-1Gb and I can download these files only by chunks 4096Kb(each http get request gives me only 4kb).

It might be to long to download it in one thread, so I want to download them, let's say in 20 threads(one thread for one file) and I also need to download a few chunks in each of these threads, simultaneously.

Is there any example that shows such logic?

Comment: If server supports range request then that your way. Learn more about [Range Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests). And then you have properly write the file data in the order.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't support range requests. I have a link on each chunk.

Comment: Okay, so you have set of links. Then you can create method called download than call that method via goroutine with each chuck link. Also use `sync.WaitGroup` for wait to finish download.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of how to set up a concurrent downloader. Things to be aware of are bandwidth, memory, and disk space.  You can kill your bandwidth by trying to do to much at once, the same goes for memory.  Your downloading pretty big files so memory can be an issue.  Another thing to note is that by using gorountines you are losing request order. So if the order of the returned bytes matter, then this will not work because you will have to know the byte order to assemble the file in the end, which would mean that a downloading one at a time is best, unless you implement a way to keep track of the order (maybe some kind of global map[order int][]bytes with mutex to prevent race conditions).  An alternative that doesn't involve `Go` (assuming you have a unix machine for ease) is to use `Curl` see here http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/13/download-with-curl/

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

// now your going to have to be careful because you can potentially run out of memory downloading to many files at once..
// however here is an example that can be modded
func downloader(wg *sync.WaitGroup, sema chan struct{}, fileNum int, URL string) {
    sema <- struct{}{}
    defer func() {
        <-sema
        wg.Done()
    }()

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 10}
    res, err := client.Get(URL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    // I'm copying to a buffer before writing it to file
    // I could also just use IO copy to write it to the file
    // directly and save memory by dumping to the disk directly.
    io.Copy(&buf, res.Body)
    // write the bytes to file
    ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("file%d.txt", fileNum), buf.Bytes(), 0644)
    return
}

func main() {
    links := []string{
        "url1",
        "url2", // etc...
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // limit to four downloads at a time, this is called a semaphore
    limiter := make(chan struct{}, 4)
    for i, link := range links {
        wg.Add(1)
        go downloader(&wg, limiter, i, link)
    }
    wg.Wait()

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, i want to implement an additional logic in order to keep track of the order.

One more question, about Go lang, in general. What if len(links) == 1000, does it mean that i will instantly create 1000 threads and only 4 of them will be active for the first time and the others will be zombie threads for a while?

I am asking, because i am a bit confused and have no idea how it affects my stack and ram.

Comment: The semaphore is blocking, so if you have 1000 links, only 4 will be processed at a time because only 4 goroutines will be running at any given time.

Comment: Yep, i understand it, but anyway, the function will be called 996 times. And each call takes at least 5*4 bytes(in this case) on the stack(x86) isn't it? it's not a big deal to allocate 5*4*1000 bytes, just want to make sure that it's fine.

Comment: You'll be fine, 4 is a really low number in production I'd probably be in the thousands. The garage collection will clean up as goroutines complete. Your real challenge filling up memory from the stored res.Body. You also probably don't want to write to file to often as it will kill the life on the drive.

Comment: Yeah, also don't like to seek too often 8)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the implementation in aws-go-sdk.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/feature/s3/manager/download.go

1. create `n` concurrent go routine
2. download the chunks in the `n` go routine
3. use `writer.WriteAt()` to seek and write to certain position.